# Nearby Messages API returns status code 2806 while publish

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am trying to publish a simple text message using Nearby API but it is returning unknown status code = 2806.Here is my sample code

```
 private void publish(String message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Publishing message: " + message);
        mActiveMessage = new Message(message.getBytes());

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            PublishOptions options = new PublishOptions.Builder()
                    .setStrategy(Strategy.DEFAULT)
                    .setCallback(new PublishCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onExpired() {
                            super.onExpired();
                            Log.i(TAG, "no longer publishing");
                        }
                    }).build();

            Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, mActiveMessage,options)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "published successfully");
                            } else {
                                Log.i(TAG, "could not publish");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Do I need to add some special permission or anything else?

Comment: We're still having this error over here if anyone has any insight:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431212/google-nearby-messages-publish-returns-2806-forbidden-android-react-native

Answer (score 6):

2806=FORBIDDEN

Did you have the api key for your app specify in the manifest and ensure that it has the right packagename and sha1 fingerprint?

Comment: `NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(code)` gives you the name of the code.

Comment: Above method returns FORBIDDEN.

Comment: I have generate API key again in google console and now its working perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Make your API key restricted to your package name and SHA1 fingerprint.

1. Go to **Google API Console**
2. Go to **Credentials**
3. If you have no **API key** yet, click Create Credentials and select API
   key. Else, select your current API key.
4. Under key restriction, select **Android apps**.
5. Enter the **package name** of your android app and **SHA1 fingerprint**.
6. To find your SHA1 fingerprint:

   - open **command prompt**
   - type your current **Java JDK bin path** (e.g. cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin)
   - type `keytool -list -v -keystore "PATH_OF_YOUR_KEYSTORE_FILE"` (Note: The debug.keystore may be found in .android folder (e.g. C:\Users\myUser\.android\debug.keystore)
   - password is **android**
   - copy the SHA1 fingerprint
7. Click **Save**

Ensure that you have the google Nearby dependency in your build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1'
```

Make sure to also enable the Nearby Messages API in the Google Console.

1. Go to **Google API Console**.
2. Go to **Library**.
3. Search for **Nearby Messages API**.
4. Click the **Enable** button beside the Nearby Messages API title.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you only subscribe/publish with an non-Activity Context (e.g. Application or Service). The library needs an Activity to show the opt-in message. Try to subscribe within an Activity (as well as from a Service).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the Google Play Services installed on your devices are up to date ? Or at least do they the match the version you are using in your build.gradle ?